# MVC multitenant application with different authentications per tenant

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, adfs

I've been searching for many hours about a viable architecture for my scenario.

We would like to have a multitenant MVC application where each tenant belongs to a different company.
Each tenant have settings where we can configure their authentication type : Customer AD or Forms.

Is it possible to allow each company to login using their own active directory ? Or by default if they don't have AD, we use forms authentication.

I've read some articles about Azure AD, AD Federation Services + WIF (or more recently OWIN), but I would like some guidance about solutions to achieve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty standard scenario in Azure AD.  You'll want to register an Azure AD app in the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com), and use the OWIN OpenIdConnect middleware to do login/session management.  If you want to also call a web API or the Microsoft Graph, you may also need to include ADAL (Active Directory Auth Library) to help exchange auth codes for tokens.

Here's a great code sample that shows you how to build a [.NET multitenant MVC App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect).  Moreover, the rest of the docs for this stuff can be found at the [Azure AD developer page](https://aka.ms/aaddev).

Answer (score 0):

Having done this before, the way I did it was to use [asp.net-identity](/questions/tagged/asp.net-identity) and per tenant override the [SignIn Manager](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/02/01/customize-authentication.aspx) via dependence injection.

The sign in manager is where the authentication takes place, so there isn't a *drop-in framework* that just does it (I am aware of), but just overriding a couple of methods in a single class is pretty easy.

Comment: So I just need to make a custom SignInManager for active directory authentication (passing AD settings for each tenant) and use the default one for forms authentication ?

Comment: This is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Azure AD B2C? You can have users sign in with their companies emails/ AD.

Take a look here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/?cdn=disable

Answer (score 0):

As per other answers, Azure AD allows multi-tenancy. Literally just selecting a check-box in the config.

However, the standard way of authentication is OpenID Connect / OAuth.

Also, you cannot change the mode of authentication.

You mention ADFS and on-premises AD. Where do these fit in?

Comment: In fact our customers could already have an active directory (on premises), so we're searching for solutions (Azure AD or ADFS ?) to use their existing credentials when they try to connect to our multitenant app.

Comment: You can do this with a federated tenant. The flow then is that AAD redirects to ADFS which then authenticates against the on-premises AD.

Comment: Or else (depending on use case) pass-through - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-pass-through-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.NET Identity along with OpenID connect, you get this functionality. ASP.NET Identity has local accounts, and with OpenID Connect to Azure AD you can have users sign in with their Azure AD account.

The application definition needs to be a multi-tenant application.

You can pretty much follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/) if you are using ASP.NET Core, and then add OpenID Connect as described e.g. [here](https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-openid-connect-in-asp-net-core/) or by just adding code similar to this after the `app.UseIdentity` calls:

```
            // Add Authentication services.
            services.AddAuthentication()
                // Configure the OWIN pipeline to use OpenID Connect auth.
                .AddOpenIdConnect(option =>
                {
                    option.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"];
                    option.Authority = String.Format(Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["AzureAd:Tenant"]);
                    option.SignedOutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
                    option.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnRemoteFailure = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                    };
                });
```

If you create a new app with Individual User Accounts, you can add the code above after the boilerplate code for Identity in the `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs`, and then you are pretty much good to go.